# I can't make ORDER BY work when doing a union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to display potentially matching data from 2 different vendor applications.  Data needs to be stacked so users can compare, then accept or reject the match.
To do this, I want to order by Upper case of Last Name, then upper case of First Name, then by system, so the SH system's record appears immediately prior to the PR system's record.  The select is working great - my problem is with the order by clause.  When I use an 'ORDER BY' of

```
ORDER BY LName, FName, BkNum,RecordType DESC
```

I get

```
RecordType  LName   FName   BkNum       PIN
SH          SANCHEZ MICHAEL 1600010808  54727
PR          SANCHEZ MICHAEL 1600010808  54727
PR          Suarez  Isaiah  1600010838  30019800
SH          SUAREZ  ISIAIAH 1600010838  30019800
SH          SYKES   ROBERT  1600010831  588572
PR          SYKES   ROBERT  1600010831  588572
```

Notice that rows 3 and 4 are in the wrong order.  I want to use the (simplified for this posting) query shown below, but when I do, I get the message,

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
Invalid column name 'LName'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 53
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
```

I have tried removing the 'UPPER' from the CASE statement, as well as adding 'UPPER' to my simplified ORDER BY statement from above.  I always get the same error message.  I'm on MS SQL 2012.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance for your time and insight!

```
DECLARE @FromDate    DATETIME, @ToDate      DATETIME, @TempSortOrder char(2)

-- For testing
SET @FromDate = CAST('07-12-2016' as DATETIME)
SET @ToDate = CAST('07-13-2016' as DATETIME)
SET @TempSortOrder = '1A'

SELECT 'SH'                    AS RecordType,
       ISNULL(LastName,'')     AS LName, 
       ISNULL(FirstName,'')    AS FName,
       SH.BkNum                AS BkNum,
       SHCX.PIN                AS PIN
FROM BkSher AS SH
JOIN BkSherCase AS SHCX  ON SH.BkNum = SHCX.BkNum
WHERE SH.ArrDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND SH.LastName like 'S%'

UNION

SELECT 'PR'                     AS RecordType,
       ISNULL(OffLastName,'')   AS LName,
       ISNULL(OffFirstName,'')  AS FName,
       SHCX.BkNum               AS BkNum,
       CX.PIN                   AS PIN
FROM BkCase AS CX
JOIN BkSherCase AS SHCX ON CX.PIN = SHCX.PIN
JOIN BkSher AS SH  ON SH.BkNum = SHCX.BkNum
WHERE SH.ArrDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate  AND SH.LastName like 'S%'

ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1A' THEN UPPER(LName) END ASC,
  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1A' THEN UPPER(FName) END ASC,
  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1A' THEN RecordType END DESC,

  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1D' THEN LName END DESC, 
  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1D' THEN FName END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1D' THEN RecordType END DESC
```

Comment: Why do you say that rows 3 and 4 are in the wrong order?  They look fine to me.  you did notice `Isaiah` vs. `ISIAIAH`, right?  See the extra `I` in the 2nd one?

Comment: Wait, What error message are you getting? Because you don't actually *list* an error message....

Comment: On a case insensitive collation ordering by UPPER or LOWER isn't going to help because all the strings are the same thing. You would need column level collation on your sort predicates for this to have a chance of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: er... is the issue that you want ALL of your columns in the order by to be in descending order? Because if so, it needs to be: `LName DESC, FName DESC, BkNum DESC, RecordType DESC`

Comment: I voted to close the question since it appears that it all comes down to a typo in the data (`ISIAIAH`) that you did not notice.

Comment: I need the results to be case insensitive.  I don't control the data - it comes from a vendor application, so there's nothing I can do about 'data typos'.  Also, the SH rows must always preceed the PR rows.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to wrap your union in an inner select. Then you can use your aliases `LName` and `FName` in an order by. i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  -- put the select with union here
) Result
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN @TempSortOrder = '1A' THEN UPPER(LName) END ASC, ...
```

If there was no `UNION` you'd have to use the same columns from the `SELECT`

**BUT** it's all inconsequential though. Unless you using a case sensitive collation `UPPER()` won't matter so it's not necessary. Either way "Isaiah" will come before "Isiaiah"

Answer (score 0):

When using union of each Query, it would not accept order by unless you have to enclose it in a parenthesis or nested query,

Try to take a look at this:

```
select all.id,all.fname
(select a.id,a.fname from
(select id,fname from table1 order by fname) as a

union

select id,fname from table2) as all order by all.fname
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I shoehorned a solution - ugly, but it works.  Performance is ok since I will have at most 3000 rows in the temp table.  I'm open to better ideas - I'm not a fan of the temp table, but on the other hand, I'm pretty happy to get the correct output.

```
-- Create temp table.
DECLARE @ResultsList table
        (RecordType      char(2),
         LName           varchar(30),
         FName           varchar(30),
         ArrDate         datetime,
         BkNum           varchar(10),
         PIN             varchar(10),
         SHRowNum        bigint             )

--Find all the SH records, and order them, putting the order into SHRowNum
INSERT INTO @ResultsList(RecordType,LName,FName,ArrDate,BkNum,PIN,SHRowNum)
SELECT 'SH',
       ISNULL(LastName,''), 
       ISNULL(FirstName,''),
       [DOB],
       ArrDate, 
       SH.BookingNum,
       SHCX.PIN,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN @InputSortOrder = '1A' THEN LastName END ASC,
            CASE WHEN @InputSortOrder = '1A' THEN FirstName END ASC,

            CASE WHEN @InputSortOrder = '1D' THEN LastName END DESC, 
            CASE WHEN @InputSortOrder = '1D' THEN FirstName END DESC)
FROM BkSher AS SH
LEFT OUTER JOIN BkSherCase AS SHCX
  ON SH.BookingNum = SHCX.BookingNum
WHERE SH.ArrDate BETWEEN @InputRecdFromDate AND @InputRecdToDate

-- Find the corresponding PR records, and copy the order from the temp table
INSERT INTO @ResultsList(RecordType,LName,FName,ArrDate,BkNum,PIN,SHRowNum)
SELECT 'PR',
       ISNULL(OffenderLastName,''),
       ISNULL(OffenderFirstName,''),
       ArrDate,
       BookingNum,
       CX.PIN,
       RES.SHRowNum
FROM tblMWBookingsCaseload AS CX
JOIN @ResultsList AS RES ON CX.PIN = RES.PIN

-- If a SH record matches several PR records, the above query results in 
-- duplicate SH records, which we don't want.  (We want to see 1 SH record 
-- followed by a list of possible matches.)  This deletes the dups.
DELETE R
From @ResultsList R
INNER JOIN @ResultsList R2 ON R2.BookingNum = R.BookingNum
WHERE R.RecordType = 'SH'
  AND R2.RecordType = 'SH'
  AND R.BookingNum = R2.BookingNum
  AND R.SHRowNum > R2.SHRowNum

-- Return sorted results.  Each SH record is followed by 
-- its corresponding PR records.
SELECT RecordType, LName, FName, ArrDate, BookingNum, PIN
FROM @ResultsList
ORDER BY SHRowNum, RecordType DESC
```